# Pgfplots/TikZ: plot positive half of axis only

Tags: pgfplots, axis

How can I tell `pgfplots` to show only the positive half of one axis, whilst still plotting the data points that fall on the negative half of that axis? E.g., with reference to this figure,

[image]

I would like to plot only the right side of the x-axis (>0), without altering anything else. So far, all my attempts have cropped the left side of the figure altogether.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Here's an example of a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    axis on top, scale only axis,
    xmin=-22.55, xmax=22.55,
    xlabel={$r/b_0$},
    ymin=0., ymax=54.05,
    ylabel={$z/b_0$},
    axis lines=center,
    xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
    ]
    \addplot [forget plot] graphics [xmin=-22.55, xmax=22.55, ymin=0.05, ymax=54.05] {foo.png};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

I've removed the code for calculating the black outline, which is long. The above MWE leads to (sorry for the quality):

[image: Figure 2]

Attempts like `axis x line=right` or `xmin=0` lead to

[image]

and

[image: figure 4], respectively.

Comment: Could you show us -- by editing your question -- what you have achieved so far by adding the (compilable) code and perhaps also an image of the result of that code?

Comment: `restrict x to domain=0:10`? (Where you might have to change 10 depending on data.)

Comment: @StefanPinnow Edits have been added.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I've tried your suggestion, but it (i) plots the whole x-axis over [xmin,xmax], and (ii) deletes the imported image.

Comment: Sorry, but I think I don't get what you want to achieve. Is the "blue" stuff also an image in your real code and you want to "crop" that image to show only the positive part of it?

Comment: Well, it didn't occur to me that your "data" was in fact an image, as you wrote "data points".

Comment: @StefanPinnow The blue stuff is an image which I want to position on the (r,z)-axes. The image should be centred around r=0, yet I want the line of the r-axis to be drawn black only for r>0. So, I want the whole image as in the first and second figures, but the line of the r-axis itself should only show for r>0. Does that help?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Sorry for the confusion. In fact, I need to plot an image (as shown) and 'data points' (an outline, as shown on the first figure). I want to position the image on top of the (r,z)-axis system, but only show the r-axis for r>0. I hope my aim is clearer now.

Comment: Yes, now it's clear. I think I misread it originally, sorry about that,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be to disable the drawing of the x-axis, and draw it manually afterwards. There are probably other possible approaches as well.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[11pt,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    axis on top, scale only axis,
    xmin=-22.55, xmax=22.55,
    xlabel={$r/b_0$},
    ymin=0., ymax=54.05,
    ylabel={$z/b_0$},
    axis lines=center,
    xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
    x axis line style={draw=none}, % disable drawing of x-axis
    clip=false % disable clipping
    ]
    % added opacity=0.1 only to make the result clearer
    \addplot [forget plot,opacity=0.1] graphics [xmin=-22.55, xmax=22.55, ymin=0.05, ymax=54.05] {example-image};

    % draw axis line
    \draw [/pgfplots/every inner x axis line, draw=black, line cap=rect] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}, 0);

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! So do you not know of any command, such as `x axis line style={draw=half}`, that would do the job instead? (Also, why did you have to add `clip=false`, if you don't mind answering?)

Comment: @A.Debugne No, I don't think that exists. Clipping has to be disabled because stuff made with `\draw` is clipped if it ends up outside the axis boundary, and that line is drawn along the axis boundary. As a result, half the line is removed. It's especially obvious for the arrow tip, try with and without clipping and you'll see that.